# Ruby on Rails Authorization isn't saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, omniauth

I'm following this: [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/)

```
user = User.new :name => auth_hash["user_info"]["name"], :email => auth_hash["user_info"]["email"]
user.authorizations.build :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"]
user.save
render :text => "Hi #{user.name}! You've signed up."
```

I was browsing the DB and inspecting table `authorization` and fount out the table is empty.
why is that?

**EDIT:**
I get this error:

> Oops, something went wrong: ["Authorizations is invalid"]

this is user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_many :authorizations

  attr_accessible :email, :name
  validates :name, :email, :presence => true
end
```

this is authorization.rb:

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  validates :provider, :uid, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :provider, :uid
end
```

Comment: Post your user model, and check the return value of `user.save` - if it's not `true`, you probably have a validation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check return values:

```
...
if user.save
  render :text => "Hi #{user.name}! You've signed up."
else 
  # do something with the errors, e.g.:
  render :text => "Oops, something went wrong: #{user.errors.full_messages}"
end
```